# Optimizing a C++ class to be as fast as a C-struct

Tags: c++, class, struct

What can be altered with the following class definition to make creation and destruction of such objects, and passing them as function arguments as fast as possible? The reason for having a class instead is operator overloading is needed.

The class definition:

```
class MyType {
    int _a, _b, _c;
    MyType(int a, int b, int c) : _a(a), _b(b), _c(c) {}
    MyType(MyType & mt) : a(mt.a), b(mt.b), c(mt.c) {}
    ~MyType() {}
    MyType operator+(MyType & op) {/* do something */}
}
```

The struct definition:

```
struct MyTypeC {
    int a; int b; int c;
};
```

And a program that should be running at almost the same CPU time regardless of whether of the two types is used:

```
void f(MyType & mt) {mt; return;}
void g(MyTypeC & mtc) {mtc; return;}

void TestCpp() {
    for (int i=1e5; --i; ) {
        MyType mt(0, 1, 2);
        f(mt);
    }
}

void TestC() {
    for (int i=1e5; --i; ) {
        MyTypeC mtc = {.a=0, .b=1, .c=2};
        g(mtc);
    }
}
```

I.e., what can be altered in MyType to make the CPU time for running the function TestCpp() almost as fast as running the function TestC()?

EDIT:

Added full list of member functions for MyType.

These are some runtime CPU timings for each respective function:

```
time (TestC)   = 0.000618 s
time (TestCpp) = 0.001373 s
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if it already wasn't just as fast... what does timing analysis show on optimized builds?

Comment: Have you tried with a profiler? what's the difference in performance?

Comment: And why do you think it will be slower than a `struct`? In C++ `struct` is a synonym for `class` but with public access by default.

Comment: How large is the difference of the run-time?

Comment: This is what you have to do: absolutely nothing. Of course, `operator+` should not take a non-const reference, and it should be a `const` member function, or a two-parameter non-member. But that won't affect speed.

Comment: Maybe you should not compare the debug builds of both versions but instead the release build. My bet is: same speed.

Comment: "The reason for having a class instead is operator overloading is needed." - you can overload operators for structs just like you can for classes.

Comment: Also, `class` and `struct` are the same thing in C++.

Comment: and your for loops are ugly. Write them well...

Comment: Sidenote: I wonder how many "hardcore C" programmers have those same myths in their minds.

Comment: The running time should be the same. BTW: you can override the operator using a struct also, you don't have to switch your definition to class for this.

Comment: I've added CPU time measurements. Still the class-version takes longer.

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1815e81eeb1a2e9b) shows that your results are obviously unoptimized. You should experience the opposite effect, if any; unless you add complexity to your constructor/destructor.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Or... this shows that the benchmark code is too short and the difference of both runs is +-1 timer tick ;)

Comment: @BitTickler nah, remove the `volatile` and you're right though.

Comment: @BitTickler I think it might optimize out the member assignment though

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is twofold:

1. Your source code is not even compiling, as such I assume you never ran the code. And as such, your question is not based on any observation. Both are equally fast. Furthermore, if you had run an optimized version of the code you would see that the optimizer generates machine code which is pretty much equivalent to a NOP for both cases. I.e. They have both the same speed.
2. `struct` and `class` are pretty much the same in C++. Default access is private for classes (which is one of the reasons why your code would not compile - private constructor); And public for structs. You can derive and template and whatnot with structs just the same way as you can with classes. There is no difference as long as both class code and struct code does the same.

Just for your amusement: IF you had bothered to actually play with your code, the resulting assembler would look like this and upon noticing, you would never have asked the question in the first place:

```
; Listing generated by Microsoft (R) Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23026.0 

    TITLE   E:\R\playground\temp\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.cpp
    .686P
    .XMM
    include listing.inc
    .model  flat

INCLUDELIB OLDNAMES

EXTRN   @__security_check_cookie@4:PROC
PUBLIC  _main
PUBLIC  ?TestC@@YAXXZ                   ; TestC
PUBLIC  ?TestCpp@@YAXXZ                 ; TestCpp
PUBLIC  ?g@@YAXAAUMyTypeC@@@Z               ; g
PUBLIC  ?f@@YAXAAVMyType@@@Z                ; f
PUBLIC  ??0MyType@@QAE@HHH@Z                ; MyType::MyType
; Function compile flags: /Ogtp
;   COMDAT ??0MyType@@QAE@HHH@Z
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_a$dead$ = 8                        ; size = 4
_b$dead$ = 12                       ; size = 4
_c$dead$ = 16                       ; size = 4
??0MyType@@QAE@HHH@Z PROC               ; MyType::MyType, COMDAT
; _this$ = ecx
; File e:\r\playground\temp\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp
; Line 9
    mov DWORD PTR [ecx], 0
    mov eax, ecx
    mov DWORD PTR [ecx+4], 1
    mov DWORD PTR [ecx+8], 2
    ret 12                  ; 0000000cH
??0MyType@@QAE@HHH@Z ENDP               ; MyType::MyType
_TEXT   ENDS
; Function compile flags: /Ogtp
;   COMDAT ?f@@YAXAAVMyType@@@Z
_TEXT   SEGMENT
?f@@YAXAAVMyType@@@Z PROC               ; f, COMDAT
; _mt$dead$ = ecx
; File e:\r\playground\temp\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp
; Line 17
    ret 0
?f@@YAXAAVMyType@@@Z ENDP               ; f
_TEXT   ENDS
; Function compile flags: /Ogtp
;   COMDAT ?g@@YAXAAUMyTypeC@@@Z
_TEXT   SEGMENT
?g@@YAXAAUMyTypeC@@@Z PROC              ; g, COMDAT
; _mtc$dead$ = ecx
; File e:\r\playground\temp\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp
; Line 18
    ret 0
?g@@YAXAAUMyTypeC@@@Z ENDP              ; g
_TEXT   ENDS
; Function compile flags: /Ogtp
;   COMDAT ?TestCpp@@YAXXZ
_TEXT   SEGMENT
?TestCpp@@YAXXZ PROC                    ; TestCpp, COMDAT
; File e:\r\playground\temp\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp
; Line 25
    ret 0
?TestCpp@@YAXXZ ENDP                    ; TestCpp
_TEXT   ENDS
; Function compile flags: /Ogtp
;   COMDAT ?TestC@@YAXXZ
_TEXT   SEGMENT
?TestC@@YAXXZ PROC                  ; TestC, COMDAT
; File e:\r\playground\temp\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp
; Line 32
    ret 0
?TestC@@YAXXZ ENDP                  ; TestC
_TEXT   ENDS
; Function compile flags: /Ogtp
;   COMDAT _main
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_main   PROC                        ; COMDAT
; File e:\r\playground\temp\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp
; Line 37
    xor eax, eax
; Line 38
    ret 0
_main   ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

Generated from:

```
// ConsoleApplication2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

class MyType {
    int _a, _b, _c;
public:
    MyType(int a, int b, int c) : _a(a), _b(b), _c(c) {}
    MyType operator+(MyType & op) {/* do something */ }
};

struct MyTypeC {
    int a; int b; int c;
};

void f(MyType & mt) { mt; return; }
void g(MyTypeC & mtc) { mtc; return; }

void TestCpp() {
    for (int i = 100000; --i; ) {
        MyType mt(0, 1, 2);
        f(mt);
    }
}

void TestC() {
    for (int i = 100000; --i; ) {
        MyTypeC mtc = { 0,1,2 };
        g(mtc);
    }
}
int main()
{
    TestCpp();
    TestC();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't include "`stdafx`" unless necessary. It could only cause confusion.

Comment: Hold in my favor that I already spent 10x more effort into the answer than was ever invested into the question. Deleting that line and switching settings to "not using..." was simply too much for my old self ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you observing actual differences? Unless there are hidden costs not shown in your sample, like virtual constructors or methods, these will generate the same machine code. In C++ the only real difference between `struct` and `class` is that the former establishes a default `public` scope for members, while the later establishes a default `private` scope.

Comment: This is more of a comment

Comment: Members, *and* base classes.